# Union and Intersection of Countable Set which each set is subset of the next set

Tags: general-topology

Sorry if my question seems trivial but I always get confused with them. Consider we have set as following image, why we cannot directly say that Union of them is the Last set and Intersection of them is the first set? If we can why in this example, author tried to prove it in another way? I always get mixed with this relation. Also consider the reverse case which we consider it in Compact space and show that their intersection is not empty (I know this but added it just for question comprehensiveness). Why cannot we directly say that the last set is the intersection and since it is not empty the intersection is not empty too? What about that sets union or intersection? Any example can be useful for me. Thanks in advance for your response and sorry if it seems trivial to you.
[image]

and the reverse case here:
[image]

Comment: We have an infinite sequence $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq...$ There is no last set here. If that was a finite sequence which ends at some $A_n$ then yes, the union would be $A_n$.

Comment: @Mark What about the proof about limit of set function? Could not be directly achieved?

Comment: The proof that you can find in pretty much any measure theory book is the simplest way to do it. (it's not a difficult proof anyway) By the way, if any sequence would have a last set then we wouldn't need compactness in order to claim that the intersection is nonempty. But without compactness this is simply not true. You may try to find an example.

Comment: @Mark Yes, It is simple but It is not directly upon An sets.  As you say if we consider n finite then we have A=An and Why he cannot claim that so we can take n to infinity and so the relation is true!! He added countable addictiveness and used it.  I know it is sounds trivial for you. But if someone asks me about them, I cannot make them convinced!

Comment: You mean, for every $n$ we have $\phi(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k)=\phi(A_n)$, and now you want to take $n\to\infty$? But what makes you think we can take limits inside $\phi$, and claim that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\phi(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k)=\phi(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)$? That doesn't follow from the definition of a countably additive function, this has to be proved.

Comment: Aha, so that's the point.  Can we claim that set An itself goes towards set A or we cannot apply that type of limit to sets? I mean that Union of countable set is equal to limit of An? Or limit of set An cannot be defined here?!

Comment: Well, there is a so called "set theoretic limit", and in the case of an increasing sequence of sets, the limit is indeed the union. But that term is not really related to the usual limit of sequences of numbers, so not sure how can it help in this proof. You can read about this term anyway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit